# How to pass a event argument as a parameter in interaction.Trigger when using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Basically i have an Event in my custom class. I will call the particular method in the custom class with the event's argument -> properties as a parameter for that method.

You can observe the actual code behind information for this.

```
instance.FileOpening += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    CustomClass.Method(e.XXproperty, e.YYproperty);
                };
```

But i want to achieve this through interaction.Triggers in MVVM. So i used the following code in xaml.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="FileOpening">
          <i:FileOpeningAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=cntrol}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

My corresponding TargetedTriggerAction class is here to get my customclass to execute the method.

```
public class FileOpeningAction :TargetedTriggerAction<CustomClass>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            ((instance).TargetObject).Method(?,?);
        }
    }
```

But my question is How can i pass the e.XXproperty and e.YYproperty in the above action to execute the method in my custom class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use also interactivity library, then you can write this :

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="FileOpening">
    <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnFileOpening"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

And in you code it will be something like

```
public void OnFileOpening(object sender, EventArgs e){//your code}
```

Comment: To add to this answer:
The "ei" namespace is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" and you need a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

Answer (score 0):

If you follow as given below, then you can pass the event arguments to the command by setting the "PassEventArgsToCommand".

add the reference :

```
xmlns:cmd="xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4""

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding FooCommand}"
             PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```