# Fire a DataGrid Cell Edit Event with MVVM Design

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

I am working on a WPF datagrid and MVVM design using Galasoft. Couple of columns are editable and I need to perform a database call during cell edit.

I am trying to capture the event during the cell edit. I am able to do this using EventToCommand option in Galsoft. But EventToCommand is applied at grid level and the event is getting fired for every cell click event. I dont want to happen this.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="AdvisorDataGrid" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" 
                                        Background="White" CanUserSortColumns="True" GridLinesVisibility="All" IsTabStop="False" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding MemberAdvisorsList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                                         IsEnabled="{Binding IsGridAdvisorsEnabled}" CanUserAddRows="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                   CurrentCellChanged="DataGrid_CurrentCellChanged"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMemberDetails,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="OnFocus">
                                    <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding NavigateToArticleCommand,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Also, to prevent every cell event, I moved the EventToCommand to the column level, but then the event is not getting fired.

Is there anyway, I can do this? Also, what's the best event name to capture the cell edit completed action? I am currently using LostFocus, but this is getting fired even my first time click.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: CellEditEnding event will fire when you will complite editing a cell.

Comment: and if you want to perform a database call you can use PreparingCellForEdit event. It will fire before cell will be in edit mode

Comment: Thanks!! But how do I handle the CellEditing in an MVVM architecture using Galasoft.

Comment: Not sure about Galasoft. See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680222/how-to-pass-a-event-argument-as-a-parameter-in-interaction-trigger-when-using-mv/16985762#16985762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a condition check to filter the column which I need to perform `CellEditEnding` action.

Basically, `OnCellEditEnding` event, I check whether the `Column.Header.equals("Column1")` then perform the action.

By default, this event will occur for all cells.